# a medium to store wealth

Tags: to-infinitive

Is the following sentence OK? Can "medium" take an infinitive as a modifier? Should "a medium" be preceded by "as"?

> Money has two main functions: a medium of exchange and a medium to store wealth.

Comment: a medium of exchange and wealth storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, no problem with that. Indeed that exact phrase has plenty of use: Google search finds lots of examples

- Bitcoin's price soars to a record high, as investors believe it could be used as a medium to store wealth. ([source](https://www.littlelaw.co.uk/2021/01/31/bitcoin-bounces-back-bitcoins-value-rises-over-the-christmas-period/))
- as a medium of payments (currency substitution) and as a medium to store wealth (asset substitution) ([The Euroization of bank deposits](http://www.economic-policy.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/BROWN-The-Euroization-of-Bank-Deposits-in-Eastern-Europe.pdf))

["medium to store wealth"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+medium+to+store+wealth%22)

These examples have the form "used as a medium",  but you can also say that "it is a medium".  So "as" is not essential.

Comment: Does "a medium of exchange" follow "functions" properly?

Comment: Yes. I'd understand the colon to mean "the functions are..."

Comment: How about this: "John has two part-time jobs: a cook and a food courier."?

Comment: Don't you think there's a problem with "The two functions are  a medium of exchange and a medium to store wealth"? It's like saying, "John's job is a teacher."

Comment: No problem. for me with any of that.

Comment: Some pedants *might* say it "should" be *The two functions are **as** a medium of exchange and [as] a medium to store wealth*. But they're just pedants. The preposition there is *entirely* optional.

Comment: "John's job is a teacher" is not *great* English.  But I wouldn't blink if it was spoken English.  But in written, editable, text I'd correct it to "John is a teacher" or "John's job is teaching maths".   The colon sentence "John has two part-time jobs: a cook and a food courier." is no problem.  The point of the colon is to avoid lengthy linking phrases.  So I'll accept that sentence with the colon standing for something like "The job titles are..."

Answer (score 0):

It is correct as a matter of English grammar. It is not the clearest expression. What is more meaningful is either “store of value” or “measure of value” depending on the specific meaning intended.